# Using netbean multiple classes open in one JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

I am working on swing based project.This project have more then 10 child classes and one main menu class which contain multiple tabs and clicking on those tabs open multiple J Frame windows but i want that without opening multiple windows everything appear in one main window.When invoke another class it replace its GUI with existent class GUI without open a new window? thanks.

Comment: Consider using a CardLayout

Comment: You can use JInternalFrame or replace JPanel

Comment: @ThusithaThilinaDayaratne: Please spell recommended class names correctly—`JInternalFrame`, `JPanel`, etc.

Comment: CardLayout or JInternalFrameboth will suit to my idea?

Comment: @SurajAli: Either one would do; please edit your question to include a [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows any problem you encounter implementing your chosen approach.

Comment: For example if i have J Frame which contain a button "Show Record" so as soon as i pressed button disappear and my Record show on same J Frame and every time whenever i pressed menu bar buttons blew window of J Frame change continuously invoking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably using `JInternalFrame` instead of the JFrame windows which you are using right now. You can use the JInternalFrame as any JComponent. For more info turn to the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html)

Using internal frames is also described in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html)

Here is also a code example:

```
//Need to have a JDesktopPane to add the JInternalFrame to
JDesktopPane desktop;

//Adding the internal frame to the JDesktopPane
MyInternalFrame frame = new MyInternalFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
desktop.add(frame);
try {
   frame.setSelected(true);
} catch (java.beans.PropertyVetoException e) {
    //Do error stuff - optional
}
```

where:

```
//The custom internal frame
private class MyInternalFrame extends JInternalFrame {

    public MyInternalFrame() {
        super("MyInternalFrame",
                true, //resizable
                true, //closable
                true, //maximizable
                true);//iconifiable

        setSize(300, 200);
    }

    public MyInternalFrame(int offsetX, int offsetY) {
        super("MyInternalFrame",
                true, //resizable
                true, //closable
                true, //maximizable
                true);//iconifiable

        setSize(300, 200);
        setLocation(offsetX, offsetY);
    }
}
```

Code sourced from [this blog post](http://java-buddy.blogspot.de/2014/02/example-of-using-jinternalframe.html)